# convert date to integer scala spark

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark

I have a dataframe, that contain,  2 columns of date `start_date` and `finish_date`; and I created a new column to add the moyen between the 2 dates.

```
+-----+--------+-------+---------+-----+--------------------+-------------------
start_date|                      finish_date|                  moyen_date|
+-----+--------+-------+---------+-----+--------------------+-------------------
     2010-11-03 15:56:...      |2010-11-03 17:43:...|                 0|
    2010-11-03 17:43:...      |2010-11-05 13:21:...|                  2|
    2010-11-05 13:21:...      |2010-11-05 14:08:...|                  0|
    2010-11-05 14:08:...      |2010-11-05 14:08:...|                  0|
+-----+--------+-------+---------+-----+--------------------+-------------------
```

I calculated the difference between the 2 dates:

```
var result = sqlDF.withColumn("moyen_date",datediff(col("finish_date"), col("start_date")))
```

But I want to convert start_date and finish_date to integer, knowing that each column contain `date + time`.

Someone can help me please. ?

Thank you

Comment: What kind of `integer`? `unix_timestamp($"start_date")` will return you a `bigint`.

Comment: Date to Int. But now I changed opinion because I think the value will be big after convert ==> So I want change it to a long int
Thank you

Comment: Philantrovert has already answered your query in the above comment

Comment: yes yes, thanks a lot for your answers
I answered you and I goes to test it, it worked well.

Comment: @philantrovert why don't you answer it below :) so that vero can mark this question as answered.

Comment: ok , you can answer it below to mark it, because I will ask the same question but the inverse this time BigInt to Date + time  :)

Comment: For converting it other way around, `from_unixtime(ts, format)`  should work. It will give you a string representing the timestamp of that moment in the current system time zone in the given format.

Comment: thanks but I'm already did it like this var DF4 = DF3.select(to_date(from_unixtime($"start_date2"))) but it changed just on date not date + time

Answer (score 3):

Considering this as part of your dataframe:

```
df.show(false)
+---------------------+
|ts                   |
+---------------------+
|2010-11-03 15:56:34.0|
+---------------------+
```

`unix_timestamp` returns the number of milliseconds since epoch. The input column should be of type `timestamp`. The output column is of type `long`.

```
df.withColumn("unix_ts" , unix_timestamp($"ts").show(false)
+---------------------+----------+
|ts                   |unix_ts   |
+---------------------+----------+
|2010-11-03 15:56:34.0|1288817794|
+---------------------+----------+
```

To convert it back to timestamp format of your choice, you can use `from_unixtime` which also takes an optional timestamp format as a parameter. You are using `to_date`, that's why you're only getting the date and not the time.

```
df.withColumn("unix_ts" , unix_timestamp($"ts") )
  .withColumn("from_utime" , from_unixtime($"unix_ts" , "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"))
  .show(false)
+---------------------+----------+---------------------+
|ts                   |unix_ts   |from_utime           |
+---------------------+----------+---------------------+
|2010-11-03 15:56:34.0|1288817794|2010-11-03 15:56:34.0|
+---------------------+----------+---------------------+
```

The column `from_utime` here will be of type `string` though. To convert it to `timestamp`, you can simple use:

```
df.withColumn("from_utime" , $"from_utime".cast("timestamp") )
```

Since it's already in ISO date format, no specific conversion is needed. For any other format, you will need to use a combination of `unix_timestamp` and `from_unixtime`.